# Stale javascript object literal date

Tags: javascript, date, object-literal

Im trying to use a javascript object literal to format time in preporation for comparison to MySql datetime values.

Heres the object.

```
var dateTime = {
    d: new Date(),
    pad: function(number) {
        return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    },
    now: function() {
        return this.d.getFullYear()+'-'+this.pad(this.d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+this.pad(this.d.getDate())+' '+this.pad(this.d.getHours())+':'+this.pad(this.d.getMinutes())+':'+this.pad(this.d.getSeconds());
    }            
}
```

Lets just say im calling this object onClick to get the date and display it in an alert box.  I keep getting the same string returned.

Example:

```
alert(dateTime.now());
```

Returns:

```
Same date every time.
```

WHY?

Comment: Do you expect `d` to automatically update itself every millisecond?

Comment: `alert(dateTime());` is not valid do you mean `alert(dateTime.now());` ? Its always the same as `.d` is initialised only once when the object is defined.

Comment: sorry, I updated the question Alex.  Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
var dateTime = {
    pad: function(number) {
        return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
    },
    now: function() {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getFullYear()+'-'+this.pad(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+this.pad(d.getDate())+' '+this.pad(d.getHours())+':'+this.pad(d.getMinutes())+':'+this.pad(d.getSeconds());
    }            
}
```

When you do `d: new Date()`, you are taking an object which contains a date/time of a moment when `new Date()` is executed, like a snapshot. That object does not show dynamic time. And because of that you always have same time displayed. Actually, that is a time of when dateTime object created.